# How to set UITableView Section to start new Section every 5 rows of cells

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I would like to know if it is possible for the UITableViewController automatically open up now section when there are more than e.g. 5 row of cells in the Table? In detail, I want items 1 to item 5 placed in Section 1, when user add more items the new items will be placed in Section 2 automatically. How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    int sections = self.YOUR_DATASOURCE_ARRAY.count / 5;
    return sections;
}
```

See `UITableViewDataSourceProtocol` reference for more info:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: the answer above is correct .But wht will be the logic for ading up sections in a table view dynamically?